# Having Trouble Loading an Image in my Java Game Window

Tags: java, image

I've been following a tutorial on YouTube to create a basic 2D Java game. I've gotten a window to pop up with my text and a rectangle on it, but I can't seem to load an image at all. There are no error messages, the image just won't appear.

The source of code that deals with the image is located under the "render" method below:

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState {
    public Menu(int state) {}

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.drawString("Test Text", 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(50, 100, 60, 120); //x y width height

        Image obama = new Image("res/obama.jpg");
        g.drawImage(obama, 200, 130);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this was located in the console:

> ```
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:Slick Build #116
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.9.3
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1600 x 900 x 32 @60Hz
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 800 x 500 x 0 @0Hz
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:Starting display 800x500
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 ERROR:Failed to initialise controllers
> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Failed to initialise controllers
>     at org.lwjgl.input.Controllers.create(Controllers.java:86)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.Input.initControllers(Input.java:603)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:263)
>     at javagame.Game.main(Game.java:36)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/java/games/input/ControllerEnvironment
>     at org.lwjgl.input.Controllers.create(Controllers.java:69)
>     ... 3 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     ... 4 more
> Wed Feb 24 21:03:43 EST 2016 INFO:Controllers not available
> ```

I can also include my main Game class if needed.

While I've taken a basic Computer Science class focusing on Java in the past, we never really focused on the graphical components, so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It states in the error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment`. You must include that to the classpath

Comment: "There are no error messages..." - all those messages that have "Exception" in your console are error messages

Comment: There is looks like you have incorrect setup of project. Fix your classpath by adding JInput jar.

Comment: And don't instantiate new objects in render method. Never!

Answer (score 0):

You've got some errors in your program that you can debug using the Exception stack trace. Those need to be dealt with first.

It seems that your biggest error is that the compiler doesn't know where to find your class `ControllerEnvironment`. Then after you get that fixed:

Read in the Image using the class [java.awt.image.BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) like this:

```
BufferedImage bi;
try {
    bi = ImageIO.read(new File("res/obama.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e){
    //Handle if file is missing
}
```

Then drawing it should be much more managable.